# How do i create a directory for a product catalogue im making?

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a product catalogue which will be browsed through database queries with the results displayed in a div, without page refresh-via ajax.

Category examples would be:

Home
Health
Entertainment

There are also subcategories for each category, i.e:

HOME:
Garden
Furniture
Plumbing
Etc.

I want to make a little directory thing that shows exactly where they are, something like:

Home >>> Garden >>> Lawn care

With each of those as a clickable link to take the person back to that specific query level.

My code is 1 .php document, involving a query and code to output the query. If output is clicked on, it triggers an ajax script which points back to and reruns the same query/output, but with different results.

This being said, i dont know how i would create a way to store and display the directory path. That i mentioned above.

I was thinking of some way that takes the category that was clicked on and passes it through the url so that the php has the value when it reloads. And then i work that variable into a clickable directory link. But the problem is I'm not sure how to do that for multiple layers.

i.e.
If someone just clicked on "garden" i could pass the garden variable through and use that in the nav, but then if someone clicked on "lawn care" i wouldnt be sure how to keep the "garden" variable because the variable i brought over via the url would now read "lawn care."

I feel like it has something to do with dynamically adding and storing the cumulative values in an array, but I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: Is the data stored hierarchically as implied by the "directory" structure?  If so, I imagine that if an ID representing "Lawn Care" was passed into the script then, from the data, you could discern its parent, its parent's parent, and so on until you reach the root of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you've described, it sounds like you want to implement bread crumbs/categories rather than directories.

If this is the case, you'd basically need to create a Categories table in your database like so:

```
Categories
id | parent_id | name
1  | 0         | Home
2  | 1         | Garden
3  | 1         | Furniture
4  | 1         | Plumbing
5  | 2         | Lawn Care
```

This would equate to a hierarchy like the following:

- Home

  - Garden

    - Lawn Care
  - Furniture
  - Plumbing

So if I want to have a product show, for instance, in *Home > Garden > Lawn Care*, I'll need to link the product to Category #5 (Lawn Care). Then I need to develop a function to do a little while loop that figures out the parent structure from there. It will need to loop until it doesn't find a parent (or until parent_id = 0). In other words, it would go:

```
I'm in Lawn Care. Does Lawn Care have a parent?
Yes -> Garden. Does Garden have a parent?
Yes -> Home. Does Home have a parent?
No -> End.
```

There are a number of ways to implement this, which is why I left specifics out.

Alternatively, you could just do this calculation on save of the product or category so it can map out the hierarchy the one time instead of every time (saving on calculations), but this would be a very simple solution that could work for a large number of products.

The benefit to doing it this way is that you can also implement product lists based on the category you're in, and from another perspective, you can create product counts per category.

Comment: Very well thought out and articulated answer. Thanks! Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLs like `\Home\Garden\LawnCare` and rewrite them using .htaccess and mod_rewrite.. And when user clicks the Garden or the Home, you can easily go back to the requested page...This is such a simple solution to the problem...

Comment: That is simple, though now you have some of the complexity that comes from needing to sanitize values from the URL, save both a display name and a URL name for each category, and check for validity so that users can't enter "custom" values to cause your site to display obscene / offensive / illegal category lists.