# How can a child tell which parent is its own in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, parent-child

I have a very quick question about a previous post that was answered. I would have posted i there but since it was already answered i think it is archived or somewhere in the annals of SO.

In regards to the chosen answer of the post below, how do i create my database so that it can determine a child's specific parent?

i.e. in the link below the answerer used the example of assigning "0" to home, "1" to furniture, garden, and "2" to lawn care. So if i were to click on lawn care how would the database know that the parent was "garden" and not "furniture, since their parent id is both 1?

[How do i create a directory for a product catalogue im making?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556657/how-do-i-create-a-directory-for-a-product-catalogue-im-making)

The database table would look like this:

```
Categories
id | parent_id | name
1  | 0         | Home
2  | 1         | Garden
3  | 1         | Furniture
4  | 1         | Plumbing
5  | 2         | Lawn Care
```

This would equate to a hierarchy like the following:

- Home

  - Garden

    - Lawn Care
  - Furniture
  - Plumbing

Comment: Because the `id` of `'Garden'` is `2`?

Comment: Worst thing is, i knew that yesterday, and forgot today. And today i was thinking in layers, as in the "2" hierarchy is lower than the "1" hierarchy.... omg so embarrassed. 

Anyways... Thanks...

Comment: No worries. Read also this slideshow (and don't worry if you get confused, it's complicated): [Models for Hierarchical Data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data). It discusses implementation (in MySQL mainly) of 4 different models for hierarchical (tree-like) data. Your design is using the adjacency model. Depending on what kind of queries you want to be running, you can choose a better model.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help! I'm gonna read it now.

Comment: @ypercube That presentation should have a subtitle : "Increasingly convoluted ways to get around MySQL's failure to implement WITH" :)

Comment: @podiluska: I find the Closure model extremely useful. I prefer it over SQL-Server's HierarchyID datatype and the recursive queries any time. Of course, if you prefer the fast course, use Adjacency (and don't complain when you can't write recursive queries in MySQL)